# next or previous item within an ordered, filtered queryset in Django

Tags: django, pagination, detailview

How can I make transitions to the next article from the post_details(DetailView), so that both the next article and the previous one are available ?

vievs.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    #queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1)
    cats = Category.objects.all()
    template_name = 'home.html'
    #ordering = ['-post_date']
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context


class ArticleDetailView(HitCountDetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    count_hit = True


    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        
        stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        total_likes = stuff.total_likes()

        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes

        return context
```

Sort by date and ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the previous or next item based on a `DateTimeField`, you can work with [**`.get_previous_by_fieldname(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_previous_by_FOO) or [**`.get_next_by_fieldname(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO). You thus can obtain the previous/next item for `stuff` with:

```
try:
    prev_stuff = stuff.get_previous_by_post_date()
except Stuff.DoesNotExist:
    prev_stuff = None

try:
    next_stuff = stuff.get_next_by_post_date()
except Stuff.DoesNotExist:
    next_stuff = None
```

Comment: Tell me how to implement in templates? {% if next_stuff %}
              <a href=" {% url 'article_detail' next_stuff.pk %} ">Next {{ next_stuff.title }}-></a>
            {% else %}
            This is the last post!
            {% endif %}

Comment: @asd: you should pass `prev_stuff` and `next_stuff` to the context when you render this.

Comment: context["prev_stuff"] = prev_stuff
                                           context["next_stuff"] = next_stuff - Gives an error message (Post matching query does not exist.)

Comment: thanks for your feedback, it makes me better!

Comment: @asd: you will need to wrap this in a `try:` except to assign `None` if no such `Stuff` exists.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did as you said and everything works fine! I'm using the whole model, not a reference to it, right?